# How to get data to Main Activity in android

Tags: android, interface

```
public class LPickerActivity extends Activity implements MediaConnectReceiver {

    //overidden method from interface
    @Override
    public void onDeviceConnected(String devName){

        Log.d(TAG,"connected device from listener"+devName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){

    }    
}
```

Here interface is getting called by `BroadcastReceiver` for every event. So now I am getting data in `onDeviceConnected` for every new event from `BroadcastReceiver`. How to get data from `onDeviceConnected`  to `onResume` of the activity.

Note: Here I first launch activity then I wait for the event to get from `BroadcastReceiver`.

Thanks

Comment: Simplest way is to save the data in an instance variable of the activity

Comment: you can simply make a static String devName.

Comment: 1. You can generate a new local broadcast and receive it in your main Activity, or 
2. If Broadcast is getting generate before onResume then use some local variables

Comment: Thanks for ur rplay . Here first onDeviceConnected is getting called later onResume. So if i save data in instance variable first time I always get null. So how to syncronize both at a time

Answer (score 0):

The data that you got from the onDeviceConnected method, put that into SharedPreferences var so that you can access it from anywhere in that activity or some other activity.